# Two "not in" in one query?

Tags: mysql

i have this sql query

```
SELECT * FROM bots WHERE id NOT IN (select botid from messages where messages.recipient = :recipient) AND NOT IN (:bots) AND messages_today < 50 limit 1
```

And when i'm executing, it returns error.
How to make this with two "not in"s and without errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are separate conditions, more like `>=` and `<=`, not like `BETWEEN x AND y`.
There is no "left hand argument" to the second `NOT IN`.

Change `AND NOT IN` to `AND id NOT IN`